How to include a sub item based on a shared field in the main table with Prisma?
model Item {
  id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  category     String
  stateId      Int
  state        ItemState     @relation(fields: [stateId], references: [id])
  relatedItems RelatedItem[] @relation("ItemRelatedItems")
}

model RelatedItem {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  category String
  itemId   Int
  stateId  Int
  state    ItemState @relation(fields: [stateId], references: [id])
  item     Item      @relation("ItemRelatedItems", fields: [itemId], references: [id])
}

model ItemState {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  Item        Item[]
  RelatedItem RelatedItem[]
}

These are three Prisma models. I want to run a findMany query on Items and include only records from RelatedItem that have the same stateId as the Item. The stateId will not be passed as a variable to the query. I could not find anywhere in the docs that describe this. How can I do this?
